# Using multiple OR conditionals in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

The number of records that I get returned by individual OR statements do not return the same number  of records when I combine the queries in one sql statement using multiple OR statements. Please can someone advise?

For example:

```
$sql1 = SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE x = '0';
$sql2 = SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE y = '0';
$sql3 = SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE z = '0';
```

combined query:

```
$sql_total = SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE x='0' OR y='0' OR z = '0';
```

The number of records I get back from sql_total is different from the combined records returned by adding up the number of records returned by sql1, sql2, and sql3 combined.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Some rows have two of the conditions being true.

Comment: think about it: is there any row where x AND y are 0? those would be returned exactly once each by $sql1, $sql2 AND $sql_total.

Comment: Check out this SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b72e1/1. Having two of the three column equal to `0` does not change anything if you run this query or if you count the number of rows with 3 singles queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in the result from this query:

```
select (x = '0') as xzero, (y = '0') as yzero, (z = '0') as zzero, count(*),
       min(id), max(id)
from t
group by (x = '0'), (y = '0'), (z = '0');
```

This will show you have many rows have different combinations of conditions being true.  I include the `id` for further investigation.